# Link URL's domain is not in list of downloadable_domains in env.php

Tags: magento2, backend, downloadable

When I am trying to add downloadable product from back end at that time below error gets popped up

> Link URL's domain is not in list of downloadable_domains in env.php

Answer (score 9):

Magento has added this feature in latest 2.3.3
You have to whitelist the domains of those links through ssh in order to save them.
To add a domain you have to run this command :

> bin/magento downloadable:domains:add www.xyz.com

In order to get all whitelisted domains

> bin/magento downloadable:domains:show

In order to remove a domain from whtielist

> bin/magento downloadable:domains:remove www.xyz.com

You can refer to the CLI [document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/reference/cli/magento.html#downloadabledomainsadd)